# Rewrite rules for using the same base slug for multiple content types

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but here is what I'm trying to achieve. I'm using [WooCommerce](http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/), and I have it setup to prepend a base slug and the product category to my product permalinks. So, my product permalinks look like this:

`example.com/shop/%product_category%/%product_slug%`

Now, I want to create another post type called "gemstone" that uses the `shop` base page in its permalinks, so they would look like this:

`example.com/shop/gemstone/%gemstone_slug%`

The problem is that all of the gemstone pages 404. This is because their URLs are rewritten so that "gemstone" is assumed to be the `%product_category%` and the `%gemstone_slug%` is assumed to be the `%product_slug%`. I'm having trouble thinking of a way around this, but URL rewriting is pretty new to me. Anyone have any thoughts?

As a bonus, another problem with the product permalinks is that their attachment pages (e.g. `example.com/shop/%product_category%/%product_slug%/%attachment%`) all 404 as well. For reference, I have opened a [bug ticket](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/875) for the attachment page issue on the WooCommerce github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution here turned out to be setting the correct priority on the `add_action` hook. Since we're all hooking into `init` to register our post types per the Codex, the priority will determine which `register_post_type` function gets called first and, by extension, the order of the generated rewrite rules.

So, I needed my "gemstone" rewrite rules to be checked before the "product" rewrite rules, so if they match, the product rules won't even be checked. It's a bit annoying that I had to use a negative value for the priority argument to achieve this because WooCommerce uses a priority of 0 for their register post type action, but that's a minor issue.

I still don't know how best to make the attachment pages work (the bonus question from above), but that is probably best left to the core WooCommerce team.